# Quadratic fit with matplotlib not really working

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, data-fitting

I was following a tutorial for data fitting, and when I just changed original data to my data the fit became not quadratic.

[image: my weird data fit]

Here's my code, thanks a lot for help:

```
# fit a second degree polynomial to the economic data
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange
from pandas import read_csv
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([1,4,12,29,54,104]) 

 
# define the true objective function
def objective(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x + b * x**2 + c
 
# load the dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/longley.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(url, header=None)
data = dataframe.values
# choose the input and output variables

# curve fit
popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y)
# summarize the parameter values
a, b, c = popt
print('y = %.5f * x + %.5f * x^2 + %.5f' % (a, b, c))
# plot input vs output
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
# define a sequence of inputs between the smallest and largest known inputs
x_line = arange(min(x), max(x), 1)
# calculate the output for the range
y_line = objective(x_line, a, b, c)
# create a line plot for the mapping function
pyplot.plot(x_line, y_line, '--', color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

I tried python matplotlib quadratic data fit, and I expected quadratic function but visually it's not.

Comment: Looks fine to me. If you are concerned about the sharp shape of your fit, that's just due to your sampling being too discrete. Change `arange(min(x), max(x), 1)` to smaller step size like 0.01.

Comment: As Michael said, I don't think there is anything wrong with your fit function, and plotting with smaller step size will make it look better. It is not exactly quadratic, but the point of fitting is you are finding parameters for a given model that best describe the data--so the line doesn't need to lie exactly on the data points if that is your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculus seems correct.

I check it with simple linear regression for LMSE (Least Mean Square Error). The result is :

[image]

The fitting appears better for large values of y than for small values of y. This is what is expected with criteria of fitting LMSE. Probably this is the criteria of fitting implicitly implemented in your software.

But the result is different for each different criteria of fitting. For example if we specify LMSRE (Least Mean Square Relative Error) we obtain :

[image]

The fitting appears better for small values of y than for large values of y. This is what is expected with LMSRE.

Of course one can specify other criteria of fitting (LMAE for example ) or many others depending on the context in practical application. For each specified criteria of fitting the fitting will be more or less different deppending on the scatter of the points.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the polynomial regression is correct an even better fitting is obtained with an exponential model equation :

[image]